# Project 'Default' not found error when installing a NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, asp.net-core

I copied the [following project](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html) from win 8.1 to windows 7 and deleted the Migration folder. Now when I run `PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration -context BloggingContext` command in VS2015 I get the error: `Project "Default" is not found`. Both the machines have ASP.NET Core 1.0 and VS2015-Update 3 installed. I get the same error if I run `Install-Package` command for any package. Project runs fine on Win8.1

**UPDATE**

I do not have the same issue when copying a project from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 or after I upgraded from windows 7 to Windows 10. Maybe, the above issue has something to do with copying a project from a higher version to lower version

Answer (score 34):

Such an error occured to me, I fixed it simply by choosing the project at the console

[image]

Comment: Indeed that seems pretty logic, some errors are sometimes so obvious...  I don't know if I should laugh or if I should cry... Same thing happened to me recently with 'Add-Migration' command' with EF CORE 1.0. I then realized no project had been selected in Default Project console droplist [sigh...]. Just selected the name of the project and I could then proceed with migration and then update... Thanks...

Comment: I don't have anything listed in "Default project". I am using CMake. Probably yet another missing integration in VS IDE. :(

Answer (score 19):

Simple solution, but I just restarted VS 2017 and I was able to run the Add-Migration "XXXXXX" command.

Comment: worked for me too... the drop down as completely empty

Comment: The usual solution to everything!

Comment: @MarcoRebsamen Are you using an SLN to manage your project or something else (e.g. cmake)?

Comment: @rbaleksandar I don't know what any of that means, so I guess I don't.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by closing down VS and reopening the solution. 
Now I can install packages with Nuget.

Also someone said something about choosing the project from the drop-down as the default project, My drop-down was blank. In case the problem you are having is similar...try restarting the solution. Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

try this:

1. Open a command prompt in the root source directory of your application (where "project.json" is)
2. Run

   ```
   dotnet ef migrations add MyFirstMigration
   ```

   and

   ```
   dotnet ef database update
   ```

For your packages try to edit your "project.json" file and add new dependencies and run:

```
dotnet restore
```

Look at:

- https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html for the ef tool documentation.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-restore for the restore documentation.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#dependencies for the "project.json" documentation

Comment: You also get "Project 'Default' not found" when you have build errors ... fix the build errors, problem goes away.

Comment: This worked for me. I can also type those same commands in PM console and they work but the original commands do not work in the console.

Answer (score 1):

that nuget you want to install is not compatible with current project framework

> - right click on project name at solution explorer panel and choose properties
> - in the application tab change target framework to newest one.
> - close and try again to install-package

Answer (score 0):

It could happen when your project’s path is too long. Simply rename folder to shorter one or move your solution to another place.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happens after removing of "Applications insight for VS2015". Installing back of "Applications insight for VS2015" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, if we close the project and open it again, the problem will be solved . The reason is that the migration command is not reloaded, thanks to Visual Studio .

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I installed some packages already but they weren't working. Naturally, I tried to re-install the packages and the same error came up for me. Turns out; problem was me not opening the `.sln` (solution) file.

Its Important to point out that you have to load your project through the `.sln` file or you'll probably get the `Project "Default" is not found` error. One solution on here says to

> I fixed this by closing down VS and reopening the solution.
> - @Preye.

While it worked for me, it confused me at first because I thought it meant to reopen the project. I had to open the project by means of the solution file.

This is an error on NuGet's GitHub:

[Error installing package to PowerShell project with poor error](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4083)

Answer (score -1):

You also get this message when your project has build errors ... Package manager Console does a build.

Fix the build errors and "project 'Default' not found" goes away.